# Split read to slave and write to master in ar_multidb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, master-slave

I am currently working in Ruby on rails I want to split connection between master-slave so that read queries go to slave and write to master I am currently using ar-multidb gem. I know it doesn't support this.

So is there a way around of doing this without using another gem like octopus or makara.

One way I can think of is setting my default connection to slave and putting write queries in Multidb.use(:default) block. But this is a lot of effort plus can cause code failures.